# Recursion Order of Operations

Tags: java, recursion, synchronous, recursive-datastructures

I am having some trouble understanding this recursion code:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] intArray = { 20, 35, -15, 7, 55, 1, -22 };

        mergeSort(intArray, 0, intArray.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(intArray[i]);
        } 
    }

    // { 20, 35, -15, 7, 55, 1, -22 }
    public static void mergeSort(int[] input, int start, int end) {

        if (end - start < 2) {
            return;
        }

        int mid = (start + end) / 2;
        mergeSort(input, start, mid);
        mergeSort(input, mid, end);
        merge(input, start, mid, end);
    }

    // { 20, 35, -15, 7, 55, 1, -22 }
    public static void merge(int[] input, int start, int mid, int end) {
    if (input[mid - 1] <= input[mid]) {
            return;
        }

        int i = start;
        int j = mid;
        int tempIndex = 0;

        int[] temp = new int[end - start];
        while (i < mid && j < end) {
            temp[tempIndex++] = input[i] <= input[j] ? input[i++] : input[j++];
        }

        System.arraycopy(input, i, input, start + tempIndex, mid - i);
        System.arraycopy(temp, 0, input, start, tempIndex);
    }
}
```

Can someone help me identify the operation order in the code?  When we call mergeSort, are we synchronously finishing the function or are we moving on to the next step and coming back to it later?

Comment: The debugger, System.out.println, or even pen and papper are great tools for situations like this.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Debugger would be great but I am currently running code on repl.it and I don't believe the website has this functionality.  Don't have the runtime installed on this computer since it is for work unfortunately.

Comment: @Matt Periodically printing could help find the order when each part of the code is reached

Comment: @Nosrep 
Yeah might be better to just use prints to find where I am at.  Will do that, thanks for the help.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yeah might be better to just use prints to find where I am at. Will do that, thanks for the help